# searching a word inside the words of a string with an if loop (bash-mac terminal)

Tags: macos, bash, if-statement, compare

I was wondering how, working on terminal on a Mac, can I find if a word is present inside a string. 
Imagine have a variable "a" containing a string with words and spaces, and a variable "b" containing a word. I would like, through an if, to check if the word "b" is contained in "a", or inside one of "a"'s words.
Thanks!

Comment: It looks, like no web searching effort was done prior to asking the question. Also, an example would be great to illustrate your explanations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use pattern matching with `==` in `[[ ... ]]`:

```
#!/bin/bash
a='I was wondering how, working on terminal on a Mac, can I find if a word is present inside a string.'
b=Mac
if [[ $a == *$b* ]] ; then
    echo Found.
fi
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks a lot. I'll better go back to study the basics

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep`

```
$ a='I was wondering how, working on terminal on a Mac, can I find if a word is present inside a string.'
$ b='Mac'
$ c='xxx'

$ grep -q $b <<< $b
$ echo $?
0

$ grep -q $c <<< $c
$ echo $?
1
```

From `man grep`

> ```
> -q, --quiet, --silent
>          Quiet;   do   not  write  anything  to  standard  output.   Exit
>          immediately with zero status if any match is found
> ```

To put it in a if-statement, use

```
if grep -q foo <<< $string; then
    echo "It's there"
fi
```

Or, if you prefer an regex-solution:

```
string='My string';

if [[ $string =~ .*My.* ]]
then
   echo "It's there!"
fi
```

Or, use a case-statement:

```
case "$string" in 
  *My*)
           echo match
    ;;
esac
```